# Does Google Track Machine ID when uploading images to Google+ profile?

Tags: google-plus, tracking, proxies

Does Google Track Machine ID when uploading images to Google+ profile?

wondering if simply using proxies and clearing browser cache (and not use chrome) is enough to keep google profiles completely separate from one another

is there an app for that?